# Get Earliest Date corresponding to the latest occurrence of a recurring name

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, select

I have a table with Name and Date columns. I want to get the earliest date when the current name appeared. For example:

| Name | Date |
| --- | --- |
| X | 30-Jan-2021 |
| X | 29-Jan-2021 |
| **X** | **28-Jan-2021** |
| Y | 27-Jan-2021 |
| Y | 26-Jan-2021 |
| Y | 25-Jan-2021 |
| Y | 24-Jan-2021 |
| X | 23-Jan-2021 |
| **X** | **22-Jan-2021** |

Now when I try to get the earliest date when current name (X) started to appear, I want 28-Jan, but the sql query would give 22-Jan-2021 because that's when X appeared originally for the first time.

**Update**: This was the query I was using:

```
Select min(Date) from myTable where Name='X'
```

I am using older SQL Server 2008 (in the process of upgrading), so do not have access to LEAD/LAG functions.
The solutions suggested below do work as intended. Thanks.

Comment: Do you by any chance mean: you want the earliest date of the latest *group* of rows with the same `Name`?

Comment: You need to provide *all* relevant information, such as your table's primary key (you have one, presumably) because, as noted, what you have provided is insufficient to support the requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is a type of *gaps-and-islands* problem.**

There are many solutions. Here is one that is optimized for your case

- Use `LEAD/LAG` to identify the first row in each grouping
- Filter to only those rows
- Number them rows and take the first one

```sql
WITH StartPoints AS (
    SELECT *,
      IsStart = CASE WHEN Name <> LEAD(Name, 1, '') OVER (ORDER BY Date DESC) THEN 1 END
    FROM YourTable
),
Numbered AS (
    SELECT *,
      rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Date DESC)
    FROM StartPoints
    WHERE IsStart = 1 AND Name = 'X'
)
SELECT
  Name, Date
FROM Numbered
WHERE rn = 1;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f3add78e6a7c259472885eb78cd2a458)

For SQL Server 2008 or earlier (which I *strongly* suggest you upgrade from), you can use a self-join with row-numbering to simulate `LEAD/LAG`

```sql
WITH RowNumbered AS (
    SELECT *,
      AllRn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Date ASC)
    FROM YourTable
),
StartPoints AS (
    SELECT r1.*,
      IsStart = CASE WHEN r1.Name <> ISNULL(r2.Name, '') THEN 1 END
    FROM RowNumbered r1
    LEFT JOIN RowNumbered r2 ON r2.AllRn = r1.AllRn - 1
),
Numbered AS (
    SELECT *,
      rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Date DESC)
    FROM StartPoints
    WHERE IsStart = 1
)
SELECT
  Name, Date
FROM Numbered
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks, but my sql version does not support the LEAD/LAG functions yet. Anything without these?

Comment: @goodsamaritan that would mean you're using a completely unsupported version of SQL Server. It is **assumed** that when you ask a question you are using supported software, and if you aren't you *need* to let the users know (normally by tagging the version). If you don't have access to `LEAD`/`LAG` you are using SQL Server 2008 or prior; as it was added in SQL server 2012 (which has about 9 months of extended support left). 2008 has been completely unsupported for over 2 years, and prior versions far longer. It's well past time you got that upgrade path sorted.

Comment: Here you go, you can simulate it with a self-join

Answer (score 1):

This is a gaps and island problem. Based on the sample data, this will work:

```sql
WITH Groups AS(
    SELECT YT.[Name],
           YT.[Date],
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY YT.Date DESC) - 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY YT.[Name] ORDER BY Date DESC) AS Grp
    FROM dbo.YourTable YT),
FirstGroup AS(
    SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES
           G.[Name],
           G.[Date]
    FROM Groups G
    WHERE [Name] = 'X'
    ORDER BY Grp ASC)
SELECT MIN(FG.[Date]) AS Mi
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6944d72cb918b3966d585580803a7c81)

Answer (score 0):

If i did understand, you want to know when the X disappeared and reappeared again. in that case you can search for gaps in dates by group.

this and example how to detect that

```
SELECT name
 ,DATE
FROM (
SELECT *
    ,DATEDIFF(day, lead(DATE) OVER (
            PARTITION BY name ORDER BY DATE DESC
            ), DATE) DIF
FROM YourTable
) a
WHERE DIF > 1
```